Postman API Invalid Credentials
I am trying to figure out how to do an API call to a site called Ongage using Postman with the POST method.
Basically, it's an API call that will send out a transactional message from Ongage.
Per the available link here: https://ongage.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/HELP/pages/947486763/Transactional+Mailing+API+Methods#TransactionalMailingAPIMethods-POST/api/transactional
Under the section that reads "POST /api/transactional", I have to use the following:
POST URL: https://api.ongage.net/<list_id>/api/transactional

So in Postman, I used POST and entered the URL above with a list_id I was provided, but I am getting back the below message:
{
"metadata": {
    "error": true
},
"payload": {
    "code": 401,
    "errors": [],
    "message": "Invalid Credentials. Please provide valid x_username, x_password and x_account_code 
    headers. x_account_code as displayed in the \"Account Profile\" page in your Ongage account."
  }
}

I used Postman before for simple API requests, but none where I have to enter username and password.
I'm not sure where I should enter it.
I was able to click on Body, and then I clicked raw so that I could enter JSON values for the username, password, and account_code, like this:
{
  "username": "username1",
  "password": "password2",
  "account_code": "account_code3"
}

But I am still getting the same message as before, stating Invalid Credentials.
Are the credentials just invalid, or am I doing this wrong?
Here is a screenshot of how I set the headers:


This is covered in the FAQ
https://ongage.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/HELP/pages/70418454/API+FAQ
*2. These are the credentials you'll need to send in the request header:
X_USERNAME: your_ongage_username
X_PASSWORD: your_ongage_password
X_ACCOUNT_CODE: your_ongage_account_code*

So on Postman, after I have selected POST, I go to the Header tab (beneath the URL box), and in the Keys, I have username, password, and account_code with the respective values.  I hit send, and I'm still getting the same "invalid credentials" message as before.  Does this mean the credentials are wrong or did I do this incorrectly?

I updated my question with a screenshot.

It's X_USERNAME, X_PASSWORD, etc.  As per the documentation.  Even the error message is telling you this.

Ohhhh - I'm supposed to be using X_USERNAME, X_PASSWORD, and X_ACCOUNT_CODE as the keys.  I get it now.  I'm getting a "404 Not Found" error now, but at least it's not the invalid credentials message.  Thank you.
